# errors in javascript and cannot catch up the bug

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to show a progress status in a div when clicking button (run at server) on the ASP.Net web page.I'm sure there may be some mistakes in my javascript, but I cannot find out the bug, please see my code below:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("     <style>");
    sb.Append(".black_overlay {");
    sb.Append("display: none;");
    sb.Append("position: absolute;");
    sb.Append("top: 0%;");
    sb.Append("left: 0%;");
    sb.Append("width: 100%;");
    sb.Append("height: 100%;");
    sb.Append("background-color: black;");
    sb.Append("z-index: 1001;");
    sb.Append("-moz-opacity: 0.8;");
    sb.Append("opacity: .80;");
    sb.Append("filter: alpha(opacity=80);");
    sb.Append("}");

    sb.Append(".white_content {");
    sb.Append("display: none;");
    sb.Append("position: absolute;");
    sb.Append("top: 25%;");
    sb.Append("left: 25%;");
    sb.Append("width: 50%;");
    sb.Append("height: 50%;");
    sb.Append("padding: 16px;");
    sb.Append("border: 16px solid orange;");
    sb.Append("background-color: white;");
    sb.Append("z-index: 1002;");
    sb.Append("overflow: auto;");
    sb.Append("}");
    sb.Append("</style>");

    sb.Append(" <div id='light' class='white_content'><div id='prostat'></div><br /><div id='dura'></div></div> ");
    sb.Append("<div id='fade' class='black_overlay'></div>");             

    sb.Append("<script language=javascript>");
    sb.Append("var dots = 0;var dotmax = 10;var timmer = 0; ");
    sb.Append("function ShowWait()");
    sb.Append("{var output; ");
    sb.Append("    output = 'Loading';");
    sb.Append("       dots++;");
    sb.Append("     if(dots>=dotmax)");
    sb.Append("       dots=1;");
    sb.Append("     for(var x = 0;x < dots;x++)");
    sb.Append("     {output += '.';}");

    sb.Append("  dura.innerText =  output;");

    sb.Append("  dura.innerText += (++timmer) + ' seconds elapsed.'");
    sb.Append("}");
    sb.Append("function StartShowWait()");
    sb.Append("{");

    sb.Append("      document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'");
    sb.Append("      window.setInterval('ShowWait()',1000);");
    sb.Append("}");
    sb.Append("function HideWait()");


    sb.Append("{document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';");

    sb.Append("    window.clearInterval();");
    sb.Append("}");
    sb.Append("StartShowWait();");
    sb.Append("</script>");

    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    Response.Flush();

    Thread.Sleep(15000);

    Response.Write("<script>prostat.innerText = 'processing first request...';</script>");
    Response.Flush();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    Response.Write("<script>prostat.innerText = 'second request finished.';</script>");
    Response.Flush();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    Response.Write("<script>prostat.innerText = 'second request finished.';</script>");
    Response.Flush();
    Thread.Sleep(3000);

    Response.Write("<script>prostat.innerText = 'second request finished.';</script>");
    Response.Flush();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);


}
```

when I click the button on the page, the DIV (id = "light" and id = "fade") are not displayed.

so can you please help me to catch up the mistakes?

Comment: You are missing one ';' at the end of the line where you have "document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'".

Comment: thanks, it's working now